# combine results from a loop in one file

Tags: r, loops, save

I create a loop like this one:

```
for (p in 1:nrow(outcomes)) {

    id <- apply(regulationtable, 1, function(i)
        sum(i[1:length(regulationtable)] != outcomes[p,])==0)

    idd <- as.matrix(id)
    test2 = subset(idd, idd[,1]==TRUE)

    result <- as.data.frame(rownames(test2))

    filename = paste("file", p, ".txt")

    write.table(result, filename)
}
```

The results of every loop will be saved as a file. I want to combine this results and create one file with all the results.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `append` argument in `write.table` you can add lines to an existing file rather than overwriting them:

```
if (p == 1) 
{
  write.table(result, "file.txt") 
} else
{ 
  write.table(result, "file.txt", append = TRUE, col.names = FALSE)
}
```

Is this what you mean?

EDIT: You might want the first run to initialize it and not append, then each other run to not print the column names ( I do assume these are the same for each table).

Comment: The warning are all the same. Like This: 
Warning messages:                                                                                    
1: In write.table(result, filename, append = TRUE): appending column names to file

Comment: @Lisann - the warning is telling you that the column names are being added again every time you are appending to the file. You should be able to open your `file.txt` and see what it means. It looks like @Sacha has updated his answer to address this problem.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. For working in R it's fine, but I'n running R in another program, and that goes wrong