# combine results from loop in one file in R (some results were missing)

Tags: r

I want to combine the results from a for loop into 1 txt file and I have written my code based on suggestion from this link
[combine results from a loop in one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404393/combine-results-from-a-loop-in-one-file)

There is one problem.  I am supposed to get 8 results (row) but I only ended with only 5.  Somehow the other results did not get into the file.  I think the problem is with the if statement but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my code

```
prob <- c(0.10, 0.20)
for (j in seq(prob)) {
  range <- c(2,3)
  for (i in seq(range)) {
    sample <- c(10,20)
    for (k in seq(sample)) {
      data <-  Simulation(X =1,Y =range[i], Z=sample[k] ,p = prob[j])
      filename <-  paste('file',i,'txt')
      if (j == 1) {
        write.table(data, "Desktop/file2.txt", col.names= TRUE) 
      } else {
        write.table(data,"Desktop/file2.txt", append = TRUE, col.names = FALSE)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the "filename" object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `if ( j == 1 )` bit is meant to check whether this is the first time you've written to the file or not.

If it *is* the first time, then it will write the column names (i.e. `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `p`) into the file (see the `col.names=TRUE`?).

If it *isn't* the first time, then it *won't* write the column names, but will just append the data.

Since you have multiple nested loops, that condition won't work so well for you: when `j==1` (i.e. for `prob=0.1`) you perform 4 other loops within. But since `j==1`, the data is getting overwritten each time.

I'd recommend initialising a variable `count` that counts how many times you've performed `Simulation`, and then changing that line to `if ( count == 1 )`:

```
count <- 1
prob <- c(0.10,0.20)
# .... code as before
    data <-   Simulation(X =1,Y =range[i], Z=sample[k] ,p = prob[j])
    if ( count == 1 ) {
        write.table(data, "Desktop/file2.txt", col.names=T)
    } else {
        write.table(data, "Desktop/file2.txt", append=T, col.names=F)
    }
# increment count
count <- count + 1 
}}}
```

Comment: @Amateur, you can also create the file outside of the loop with no data, just headers, and then append to the file within the loop (avoiding the if and else statements and worries about which level of the loop should be indexed to create the first file).  This also allows you to append to the file in another run of the loop if you wish (say to expand variable space).

Comment: Thank you Etienne Low-Decarie.  The problem is I don't know how syntax-wise.  I'm a novice in R and computer programming in general.